# Converting String Data to Numeric data

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, machine-learning-model, data-cleaning

I want to convert String data to Numeric data as the Decision tree is only accepting numeric data. When I had Binary String data like Ever_Married[Yes/No] I converted using the `.replace`  method to Numeric data. But now I have an attribute with 5 different options[Private, Self-employed, Children, Govt_job, Never_worked]. Is it okay to use `.replace` to map these attributes to five different Numeric values? will it affect my model and is this good practice?

Comment: How is “ever married” continuous? Likewise, how is your five-category employment variable continuous?

Comment: Ohh sorry for the mistake, ever_married and employment attributes were String and I wanted to convert them to Numeric variables. Because an error was coming the decision tree cannot take string variables. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged `scikit-learn` , then you can use its function `preprocessing.LabelEncoder()` to convert categories to numerical values. And yes, this is a good practice.

```
from sklearn import preprocessing    
label_encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
label_encoder.fit(my_dataframe["status"])
```